# How do I add IRCTC tickets to iPhone Wallet

Tags: iphone, wallet

I am residing in India. I have iPhone 5s running 9.3.2 I would like to add IRCTC tickets to iPhone Wallet. How do I add them ?

Comment: Does this help? If it does, I'll make it an answer. Apparently it converts then stores the tickets into iPhone Wallet
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/rail-pass-irctc-pnr-status/id902487234?mt=8

Comment: From the screen shots, I believe post PNR search, ticket gets added to the wallet. PNR search doesnot work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

You can either get [Indian Railway PNR & IRCTC Info](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/indian-railway-pnr-irctc-info/id888197080?mt=8) or [Rail Pass™ - IRCTC PNR status enquiry](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/rail-pass-irctc-pnr-status/id902487234?mt=8). Add Indian Railway train ticket to Passbook using RailPass.

Then book the ticket and use the PNR to generate pass [for Wallet] using these apps. Once the pass is generated, you can add it from there itself.

I personally prefer Rail Pass™, as it is slick, fast and bug free. More over it doesn't irritate us with ads.